# Access violation after exit using QSystemTrayIcon from PyQt4

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I wrote a simple class for notifying user using tray balloon message. Here is the code:

```python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class TrayInformer():
    def __init__(self, icon_file):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
        self.tray_icon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(
            QtGui.QIcon(icon_file)
        )

    def notify(self, title, message, wait_time=1000):
        self.tray_icon.show()
        self.tray_icon.showMessage(title, message)
        time.sleep(wait_time / 1000)
        self.tray_icon.hide()

inf = TrayInformer('timeico.ico')
inf.notify('Error', 'Connection refused', 5000)
inf.notify('test', 'test', 500)
```

After running it I sometimes get: `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to instantiate QSystemTrayIcon with parent specified. I've had resembling random crashes on exit, and surprisingly tray icon appeared to cause the problem

> <...> the problem is probably the random order in which C++ 
>   instances get destroyed. Explicitly del'ing a object, or giving it an  appropriate parent is the best way to deal with it.
>   [QSystemTrayIcon still crashed app (PyQt4 4.9.1)](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/QSystemTrayIcon-still-crashed-app-PyQt4-4-9-1-td4976041.html)